# How to route all traffic to local socks5 server?

Tags: python, networking, proxy, socks

I've implemented **SOCKS5** server (which forwards connections **over SSH** to remote), it runs on *127.0.0.1:7070*.

Now I'm trying to **route all traffic through it**.
I thought it's impossible, but apps like *proxifier* can do it... but how?

I'm looking for the *Python* solution on *Windows*. Any ideas?

Or at least make Chrome/IE to work this way...